# Jquery onclick not woking in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

im trying to limit the allowed input characters to 4, this is the code i have so far, after implementing the character limitation, the onclick function for the buttons stopped working.Thanks for you time.

```
qty.oninput = function () {
   if (items == '') {
      echo("4");
   }                
   else if (this.value.length > 4) {
      echo("0");
   }
}
```

Comment: `echo` is not valid Javascript statement, use `console.log()`

Comment: What is the value of `qty`? I see no jquery in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the maxlength attribute in your input tag..